# Deriving tight bounds from Chebyshev inequality for known distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X\in [0,1]$ and finite $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$. I am using the Chebyshev inequality to bound $|X-E[X]|$:

$$\Pr\left[|X-E[X]|<M\sqrt{Var[X]}\right]\geq 1 - \frac{1}{M^2}$$

I set $M=10$ and obtain an upper bound with $0.99$ probability.

However, when I check the bound empirically, I see that the bound is very loose: one order of magnitude greater than the empirical results. Is this expected from a Chebyshev bound? I read it is a very conservative bound, but one order of magnitude seems almost a useless bound.

Assuming that this difference is expected, can I use the fact that $X\in[0,1]$ to obtain tighter bounds?

Alternatively, I read that Chernoff bounds are tighter than Chebyshev's, but I do not see $|X-E[X]|$ in Chernoff's inequality --which is what I want to bound.

Comment: Would you be able to obtain more info, e.g. 3rd or 4th moments? While Chebyshev's is quite week, it's hard to come up with a tighter bound with just the mean and variance.

Comment: @TomChen assuming that the 3rd or 4th moment exists and is finite, how do you propose to use them to obtain a tighter bound?

Comment: Wikipedia gives [examples where Chebyshev's bound is tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Sharpness_of_bounds) and those examples have range $[-1, 1]$ which can be easily rescaled to your $[0,1]$.  So in general, what you are asking for is not possible, unless you have more info about the r.v. $X$.

Comment: Empirically, the Chebyshev bounds are clearly not tight though.

Comment: Yes, the Chebyshev bound is not tight for your specific $X$, which we know very little about. What Tom is saying is that it might be possible to find a bounded $\tilde{X}$ with identical expectation and variance as $X$ for which the bound is tight, so Chebyshev provides the best bound possible given only $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{V}$. Can you provide more information on your specific $X$? For example, some improvements are possible if $X$ was the mean of independent random variables or if $X$ is unimodal.

Comment: Check out this paper which utilizes higher moments for sharper bounds:
https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/2718/SWP-4025-40968492.pdf%3Bjsessionid%3D48FBFC498E588A9F28C0D95108D22334?sequence%3D1

Comment: So, the reason why I'm asking this question is that I use Chebyshev to bound the error of an estimator. In this case, $X$ is an estimator of the mean, and I want to bound how _far_ it is from the mean. Chebyshev allows me to do that without knowing the actual expected value ($E[X]$). However, when I try to use Chernoff, the expected value (an unknown) ends up in the bound expression. How would one go about obtaining a tighter bound than Chebyshev without knowing the expected value in advance?

Comment: How can a random variable be continuous? On what space is it defined?